# customization of org-agenda-custom-commands not seen on next emacs instantiation

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

GNU Emacs 30.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0, NS appkit-2022.70 Version 11.7.6 (Build 20G1231)) of 2023-05-30
Org mode version 9.6.12 ( @ /Users/brucer42/.emacs.d/elpa/org-9.6.12/)

I customized the variable `org-agenda-custom-commands` via the `F12-C` ( `C-c a C` ) route to customizing the variable. It gets written to `init.el`. It operates properly. I am setting `org-super-agenda-groups` to `nil` for one of the agenda views. Actually a new command, `x`, though I *would like* customize the `F12 t` command but its setup is not visible in this variable.

When I restart emacs the customization is gone, though it still exists in `init.el`.

Comment: Please show the code. Show what's in your init.el file for this.

Comment: You're using a development version of Emacs - not a released version. Are you sure that the version of Org you have works with your Emacs dev version?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had "(org-babel-load-file "~/git/org-mode-doc/org-mode.org")" in my init.el file AFTER custom-set-variables WHICH OVERWROTE my customization. I changed the

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands" in the babbled file by adding
              ("t" "Todo" tags-todo "\"\""
               (
                (org-super-agenda-groups nil)
                ))
```

which affects the F12 t command in the way I desire ALTHOUGH it adds an entry to the *Agenda Commands* buffer. Definitely workable. My fingers don't have to learn a new command!